# Importing a file with space in name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

How do we import a function from a file, say, 'New File.py' in python in a different file (both being in the same directory)?
If it were, say, 'This_thing.py', then we could simply type

```
from This_thing.py import *fn_name*
```

What is the format of importing stuff from the file with the said name-type?
TL;DR,

```
from New File.py import fn
```

doesn't work. What to do?

Comment: Rename the file.  A programmer should avoid spaces in filenames wherever possible---certainly in parts that are not end-user-facing, such as source code files. It may or may not be technically possible to work around this particular case (using functional forms of import) but I can almost guarantee that this won't be the last problem that space will cause.

Comment: I understand that, and have saved file names accordingly. But I was just curious whether there was a way to open such files.